# Use one instance of a Service per Component

Tags: angular, angular8

Using Angular 8 I have two components:

```
@Component({ selector: 'a' })
export class A_Component {
    constructor(dataService: DataService) { }
}

@Component({ selector: 'b' })
export class B_Component {
    constructor(dataService: DataService) { }
}
```

And the DataService is as follows:

```
export class DataService {
    public getValue(): Observable<number> { }
    public setValue(value: number) { }
}
```

Components A and B use DataService to communicate which their child (grandchild, ...) components.

But I want each Component, A and B, to have their own instance of DataService.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use in this way

```
@Component({ selector: 'a',
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class A_Component {
    constructor(dataService: DataService) { }
}

@Component({ selector: 'b',
    providers: [DataService]
})
export class B_Component {
    constructor(dataService: DataService) { }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your DataService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})export class DataService { ...
```

Comment: I think that makes the service a Singleton

Comment: Yes it is. If you don't what it, i think you can do two different instances putting: `@Component { 
...
 providers[DataService]
}`

Comment: Avoid any confusion: this makes the service a Singleton and does the opposite of what the OP was asking for.